# How to split routes in Akka Http

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

What is the best way to split routes that need `implicit ActorSystem` to different files? Suppose I have this (non-working) code

```
// in UserRoutes.scala
object UserRoutes {
  val route: Route = ???
}

// in OrderRoutes.scala
object OrderRoutes {
  val route: Route = ???
}

// In MyApp.scala
object MyApp extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem(Behaviors.empty, "my-system")
  implicit val ec = system.executionContext
  
  val route = UserRoutes.route ~ OrderRoutes.route
  
  Http().newServerAt("localhost", 8888).bind(route)
}
```

All these routes make HTTP requests so they require the presence of `ActorSystem`, what is the best way to pass it? Make objects into classes and pass it to constructor or is there something more clever?

Comment: I'd stay on a classic (lightweight) dependency injection pattern for scala, that is how you say, convert routes in classes and put ActorSystem  in constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have something like

```
// in UserRoutes.scala
object UserRoutes {
  def route(implicit sys: ActorSystem): Route = ???
}

// in OrderRoutes.scala
object OrderRoutes {
  def route(implicit sys: ActorSystem): Route = ???
}
```

In your app, you have the actor system implicitly and then you will be able ton keep `val route = UserRoutes.route ~ OrderRoutes.route`  as it is.

I would usually use a class if I have to use some services

```
class UserRoutes(auth: AuthService, profile: ProfileService)(implicit sys: ActorSystem) {
    val route : Route = ???
}
```